# Are there are any surprising diffeomorphisms?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Two smooth manifolds are often viewed to be equivalent if there is a diffeomorphism between them. Are there examples of two manifolds that one would not expect to be equivalent (in this sense), but in fact are?

Comment: I take it that something like the complements of the [Perko pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perko_pair) doesn't count? It was a surprise that these manifolds were homeomorphic. But you specifically mentioned diffeomorphisms. Do you want examples that are obviously homeomorphic but that one would expect to not be diffeomorphic? Like maybe two differentiable structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that don't look the same but are?

Comment: For a very low-dimensional example, the torus connect summed with $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is diffeomorphic to three copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.  While it's not terribly difficult to show, I found this initially surprising.

Comment: There are pairs of manifolds $M$, $N$ that are not diffeomorphic, but such that $M\times R^n$ is surprisingly diffeomorphic to $N\times R^n$. A 3-punctured sphere and a once punctured torus ($n=1$? 2?). (The interior of) the Mazur manifold and $\mathbb R^4$, $n=1$. The complement of Alexander's horned sphere and two copies of $\mathbb R^3$, $n=1$. Homotopy equivalent 3d lens spaces, with large $n$. Pairs of high dimensional lens spaces have to be chosen more carefully, but only require $n=1$. Homotopy eq 3d lens spaces also become diffeo after cross by $S^3$, which is even more surprising.

Comment: Any closed manifold is diffeomorphic to a connected component of the zero set of some multivariable polynomial. Any closed manifold is diffeomorphic to a connected component of the configuration space of a planar linkage.